# Unable to append new object to Realm array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I'm trying to append data submitted by user to a Realm array.

I have two Realm Data Models: `Months`, the parent category that links to  `Ledgers`:

```
class Months: Object {
@objc dynamic var dates = ""
let ledger = List<Ledgers>()
}
```

and

```
class Ledgers: Object {
@objc dynamic var amount: Double = 0.0
@objc dynamic var date: String = ""
@objc dynamic var notes: String = ""

var parentCategory = LinkingObjects(fromType: Months.self,
                                    property: "ledger")
}
```

Now, I create a month array in my `MonthsTableViewController` using an IBA:

```
@IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        
        var textField = UITextField()
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add Month", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { action in
            let newDate = Months()
            newDate.dates = textField.text!
            self.save(date: newDate)
            self.load()
        }
        
        alert.addAction(action)
        alert.addTextField { alertTextField in
            alertTextField.placeholder = "Add New Month"
            textField = alertTextField
        }
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

The new Month gets created just fine, and the new Month gets added into the `datesArray` and segues to `TransactionViewController`  when selected from the TableView.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLedger", sender: self)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! TransactionViewController
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            destinationVC.selectedMonth = datesArray?[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
```

All of this works perfectly. The `datesArray` is stored into the var `selectedMonth`, which is on the destination's VC.
The destination has a barButton that triggers a popOver segue, which is a view,`TransactionCreateViewController`,  that allows the user to input the data for the `Ledger`,and then a `Submit` button that is supposed to append this data to the `selectedMonth` array.
But it won't. I can't assign a temporary constant to the `selectedMonth` array.

```
@IBAction func submitButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let transactionsArray = TransactionViewController()
        
        let amount = amountTextField.text
        let amountDouble = Double(amount!)!
        let note = noteTextField.text!
        let date = dateTextField.text!
        
        if let currentCategory = transactionsArray.selectedMonth {
            do{
                try self.realm.write{
              let newTransaction = Ledgers()
                newTransaction.amount = amountDouble
                newTransaction.date = date
                newTransaction.notes = note
                    currentCategory.ledger.append(newTransaction)
                }
            }catch{
                print("Error creating new Item \(error)")
            }
        }
```

The Button `submitButtonPressed` works. But the append won't work because I cant assign `selectedMonth` to a new Constant. Thank you for taking the time to help.
If it'll help, I'll pass along the GitHub of the project.

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: @ChrisShaw No error message, just doesn't assign the const, so it won't append.